# Store first name of user using foreign key on User model django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

right now I'm working with a blogging system which I am making without using an admin site of django. So, I have to create a blog post models and views functions that store the blog data to database manually.In that I have used User login with custom user models and a foreign key for store logged user's first name in `BlogData` database from `User` model.

My problem is that I cant directly connect to user's first name by views.Is there any way to do it.

Here is my code,

Models.py (BlogData)

```
from django.db import models
from login.models import User

# Create your models here.


class BlogData(models.Model):
    blogger_name = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='blogger_name')
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    blog_title = models.TextField()
    blog_subtitle = models.TextField()
    blog_body = models.TextField()
    blog_baseimg = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics',null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.blog_title
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import languages,BlogData

def submit_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        blg_tt = request.POST['blog_title']
        blg_stt = request.POST['blog_subtitle']
        blg_cnt = request.POST['blog_content']
        blg_img = request.POST['blog_img']



 #Problem is what to write in blogger_name

        data = BlogData.objects.create(blogger_name = <?????>,blog_title=blg_tt,blog_subtitle=blg_stt,blog_body=blg_cnt,blog_baseimg=blg_img)
        data.save()

        return render(request,"index.html")
```

Models.py (Custom User Model)

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser,BaseUserManager

# Create your models here.
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True
    def _create_user(self,email,password,**kwargs):
        email = self.normalize_email(email=email)
        user = self.model(email=email)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using = self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self,email,password = None,**kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('is_staff',False)
        kwargs.setdefault('is_superuser',False)
        return self._create_user(email,password,**kwargs)

class User(AbstractUser):

    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(unique = True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can directly do that using 'request.user.username'

```
data = BlogData.objects.create(blogger_name = request.user,blog_title=blg_tt,blog_subtitle=blg_stt,blog_body=blg_cnt,blog_baseimg=blg_img)
```

Comment: I had tried that method but it is showing me an error like `Cannot assign "'some string value'": "BlogData.blogger_name" must be a "User" instance.`Also, I had assigned username to None so, the database will store that value as null

Comment: yeah its because in banner_name you have to put user object so you dont need username you need user object answer is updated